# Xamarin iOS container for controls

Tags: ios, xamarin, containers, settings, profile

I'm new in Xamarin world and currently starting a basic app development. I'm trying to build some profile settings view a bit similar to what WhatsApp's profile view looks like, but didn't find any appropriate control to wrap up some child controls. The idea is to make something like this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq4Ci.png).

Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sushi, thank you for the answer. However I was referring to the touchable options that we have in the view attached like "**Starred Messages**", "**Accounts**", "**Chats**" and _mainly the option which contains the profile picture and the user name_. They look and feel like touchable table cells..

Comment: Oh... those "controls", yes they must probability custom UITableViewCells.    In terms of layout, that image appears to be a collection of grouped custom cells (UITableViewCell) within a UITableView. The Profile image cell would be a custom UITableViewCell while all the others are std cells and they all have their disclosure indicator enabled.

Comment: Review the `Table Rows` section of the HI guidelines for an overview with links to dev docs:  https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/tables/